# RigidBody and collision.contacts

Tags: unity-game-engine, collision

I'm trying to re-invent the wheel once again for a 2.5D platformer.

I tried some things with the CharacterController but it only send the "sides" info, not if it's coliding specifically left or right.

So now I'm working with RigidBody and the OnCollisionEnter() function

So thing is, all points returned by the collision.contacts seems to have some priorities. Here is what I have in game

- the green box is the BoxColider
- the red cubes are contact points from `collision.contacts` returned on collision from the RigidBody

[image]

As you can see, eveb if I touch a wall, all the contacts points are on the "ground" side of the Box.

If I jump :

[image]

I have point where I need them (here left side) because in air. But once I touch the ground I lose all left/right points from the returned array. All points go back to what we see in the first screenshot.

And so I have nothing to know when the Box is touched on the sides (and specifically left or right).

Any idea ? or better methods ?

Thanks !

Comment: Is there any code you used? I'm no expert, but maybe there is sth. lost?

Comment: I didn't show code because there is nothing fancy here. In OnClissionEnter() I keep the collision.contacts array and in a OnDrawGizmos() I draw all points.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could try to do your stuff with

```
OnCollisionStay()
```

to get all the contacts points.
from http://unity3d.com/support/documentation/ScriptReference/CharacterController.html